# How to use RouterLink with Microsoft FluentUI React Link component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-router-component, fluent-ui

Pretty straight forward. I've seen examples of React Router `Link` usage on other [Microsoft Fluent UI](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web) controls. I have not found a way to use it with the Fluent UI `Link` component though.

Answer (score 5):

Was able to get this working using the `as` prop found in the [Fluent UI Link implementation section](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/link#implementation):

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link as RouterLink } from 'react-router-dom';

import { Link } from '@fluentui/react';

const ComponentName: React.FC = () => (
  <Link as={RouterLink} to="/pathName">
    Link Text
  </Link>
);

export default ComponentName;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the prop `onLinkClick` on the Nav,if you prevent default and push to react router history instead you'll get the same behaviour without affecting the look and feel of fluent ui

```
import React from "react"
import import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom"
import { Nav } from "@fluentui/react"

class MyNavComponent extends React.Component {
    onLinkClick(evt, item){
        evt.preventDefault()
        this.props.history.push(item.url)
    }
    render(){
        return <Nav
            onLinkClick={this.onLinkClick.bind(this)}
            isOnTop
            groups={your..groups..here}
        />
    }
}
export const MyRoutedNavComponent = withRouter(MyNavComponent)
```